# Is this an OR or a conditional probality math syntax misunderstanding in a uniform distribution exercise

Tags: terminology, self-learning, uniform-distribution

Hello I have a problem with mathematical or statistics syntax in a uniform distributed question check the f) question

[image]

I check Mathematical Statistics with Applications Wackerly's book and I not finded examples or exercise solving or proposals using this syntax.

Comment: That is a [conditional probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability).

Comment: Yeah this is a conditional probability, the probability that $x > 4$ *given* $x < 23,$ and it's defined as $\frac{\text{P}(4 < x < 23)}{\text{P}(x < 23)}$

Comment: It would be rather silly if this were an "or": it is always true that $x>4$ or $x<23.$

Comment: thk u stephen i will add some resolution in answer for not close this question i dont know. @DavidK if were OR the probability is 1 because take all the interval for example occurs with probs about billiards color ball selection is always truth mathematically or programming but in this case the prob would be 1.

Comment: Perhaps I should have said "obvious" or "trivial" rather than "silly" to describe the "or" interpretation. Yes, if it's always true then the probability is $1.$

Comment: if you invert the comparison operators $ P(x<4 $ OR $x> 23) $ is not so silly that interpretation can be a good question @DavidK I thought in poisson distribution exercises there are exercises using or.

Comment: Sure, $P(x<4 \text{ or } x > 23)$ is (for many distributions) a non-trivial thing you can try to compute. That's why we need to be sure we use some symbol other than a vertical line to signify "or." Other than in programming languages I don't think I've often seen a vertical line used that way.